# Setuptools: use build variants with different required packages

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, sdist

I want to make a source distribution (sdist), which needs to be different for the development and the target platform in terms of required packages.

More concretely, when I package for the Raspberry Pi (target platform), I don't require `opencv-python`, because OpenCV is built from sources there, but on development PCs (Ubuntu), I require `opencv-python`.

I tried to follow some tricks like this to pass in an `--raspi` parameter into the `setup.py`:

```
install_requires = [
    'opencv-python >= 4.1.1',
    ...
]

if "--raspi" in sys.argv:
    install_requires = [req for req in install_requires if not req.startswith('opencv-python')]
    sys.argv.remove("--raspi")

setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=install_requires
)
```

When I run `python3 setup.py sdist --raspi`, this approach works to a degree that the generated `./dist/mypackage.tar.gz/mypackage/mypackage.egg-info/requires.txt` does not contain `opencv-python` anymore.

But when I run `pip3 install ./dist/mypackage.tar.gz`, I still get an error such as:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python>=4.1.1 (from mypackage==0.1) (from versions: none)
```

This is also when I pass `--install-option="--raspi"` to `pip3 install`, which I read somewhere would be a way to pass an argument into `setup.py` again when run from `pip`.

When I manually edit the distribution `setup.py` (`./dist/mypackage.tar.gz/mypackage/setup.py`) and remove `opencv-python` from the required packages, then the pip3 install works.

Are there other ways to have different sets or requirements for different builds? E.g. use two different `setup.cfg` files (how?), each specifying their set of packages? I wouldn't like that approach much, as I would have mostly duplication in those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the environment markers (as specified in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers)) to restrict the requirement to a particular platform:

```
install_requires = [
    'opencv-python >= 4.1.1; platform_machine == "x86_64"'
]
```

This will install `opencv-python` on an x86_64 arch, but skip it on ARM, PPC etc.

Comment: Very nice - fits my need perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @hoefling's answer, I also found this by now:

```
extras_require={  # Optional
        'dev': ['check-manifest'],
        'test': ['coverage'],
    },
```

From the [pypa sampleproject](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py#L155). This I would invoke by `pip install sampleproject[dev]`.